# how to save and load an object

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Currently, I am using WPF. I have two windows I-e window1 and window2. window1 has a button to navigate to window2; window2 has also a button to go back to window1. window2 has many controls also user-controls. The case is whenever I navigate window1 to window2, I have to create new object of window2 due to some reasons. I know singleton pattern but cant apply here.

Now, on unload event of window2 I saved window2's object in a static class(I save "this" to static class). when user will again navigate here, I want to load saved object rather than constructing new object.

Is there any method to load saved object in current object that's going to construct ? I-e somewhere in constructor or load I may load saved object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to keep an instance of `Window2` as a property of `Window1`. However, if the problem is that `Window2` is loading slowly this isn't a good solution. Try figuring out what causes those slow loading times and fix it

Comment: actually I have to load saved object(that's window2 object) in window2's object I-e when user come twice here rather to constructing new one I want to load previous one while I am in new window2 object that just start constructing

Comment: I know this will not help you here, but pleas **don't do this** - this screams *bad design* at me. You have state so pass it around instead of hacking together some UI-spaghetti

Comment: Again, saving an instance is a solution, but it is a bad one. Instead you should try to figure out what is causing the slow loading and address it directly (Either by using threads or performance tuning)

Comment: actually I am using devexpress metro style navigation(they don't have docs for this as they said its extension) and I only register my view(to whom I am calling window2) then each time I press to goto window2 it creates new object.
That's why I want to load saved object when constructor of window2 called again

Comment: Why not show/hide the window2 instead of loading/unloading?

Comment: Actually its a custom view as devexpress define. I only register it then creation of objects library handles itself

Answer (score 2):

As it is tagged `wpf`, you definitely should take a look at `mvvm`. Instead of *passing data between forms* you will have two `ViewModel`s (for each form) to hold all associated with UI data and some `Model`s to hold the rest. And those view models (and models) will persist between forms closing/opening, means no need to pass anything or save/load.

If you need to actually save data (to example, different sets of states or for the data to survive exit/start application), then have a look at *serialization*. My favorite is `XmlSerializer`/`XmlDeserializer`, as it's easy to control, easy to change (edit data) and easy to support versioning. There are dozens of tutorials around, simply search for "c# serialization" with optional words "xml", or "binary" or even "protobuf".